# How can I make my trigger button show once I hit the escape key on a dialog box?

Tags: jquery, dialog

Here is the ui-dialog popup I've created. The goal is when the popup is visible, the button that triggers it is hidden. When the popup is hidden, the trigger is visible and clickable.

I'm looking for the following condition:

1. The escape key closes the form and unhides the trigger button

   ```
   //foo_trigger is a button that opens the popup form, foo_popup
   $("#foo_trigger").hide();

   //Opens the popup form
   $("#foo_popup").dialog({
       resizable: false,
       height:275,
       width:500,
       modal: true,
       buttons: {
           //foo button submits the form
           "foo": function () {                

           },
           //Closes the form and unhides foo_trigger button
           "Close": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $("#foo_trigger").show();
           }
       }
   });
   ```

I'd prefer whatever the answer is to only effect this popup and not have it globally effect the escape key and enter key at all times

Comment: Something like that? `if($("#foo_popup").dialog("isOpen")){ $("#foo_trigger").hide(); } else {$("#foo_trigger").show();}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to bind and unbind the keyup event handler when the dialog opens and closes:

```
function keyupHanlder(e){
       if (e.keyCode == 27) {
           $("#foo_trigger").show();
       }
}

$("#foo_popup").dialog({
   ...
   open: function(e, ui){
       $(document).bind('keyup', keyupHandler);

   },
   close: function(e, ui){
       $(document).unbind('keyup', keyupHandler);
       $("#foo_trigger").hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: This is the best answer given because it doesn't effect the key at all times. I'm still not sure if this is the best method but it works for now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
 $(document).keyup(function(e) {
      if (e.keyCode == 27) {// esc
          $("#triggerbutton").show();
      }   
    });
```